# Database File Not Existing in Flask Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, web

I have created a database in Flask Python

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///site.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class user(db.Model):
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True,nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True,nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User Details \n Name:{self.username}\n Email:{self.email} \n"

class product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    item_name = db.Column(db.String(10),nullable=False,unique=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer,unique=False,nullable=False)
    Currency = db.Column(db.String(3),unique=False,nullable=False)
    Category = db.Column(db.String(15),unique=False,nullable=True)
    product_image = db.Column(db.String(20),unique=False,nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Product Details \n Name: {self.item_name} \n price: {self.price}\n"

db.create_all()
```

I am currently creating an e-commerce site as a project and I'm following Corey Schafer's online tutorial on Flask to do so

A file named site.db is supposed to be created , I have searched my entire project repository by no file named site.db was created

Where did I go wrong? Please help me! I am beginner programmer trying to learn web development with flask

Comment: Have you tried creating the database with `db.create_all()` in the console?

Comment: @patrickyoder I did

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving your database in your project directory, but at your user´s root level. Instead of this: `sqlite:///site.db`. You should use something like this: `sqlite:////absolute/path/to/foo.db`

From [documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/)

```
#Unix/Mac (note the four leading slashes)
sqlite:////absolute/path/to/foo.db

#Windows (note 3 leading forward slashes and backslash escapes)
sqlite:///C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\foo.db

#Windows (alternative using raw string)
r'sqlite:///C:\absolute\path\to\foo.db'
```

Comment: I tried both of them. Still file not saving :(

Comment: both? you have to use the format according to your OS.

Comment: If you are in an unix system: `sqlite:////~/foo.db` Then check your `home` directory

Comment: By both I mean - sqlite:////absolute/path/to/foo.db ;